# Angular ng-class setting proper class (confirmed in page source) but won't apply styles

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

Yes...it's tabular data.

So, the question title explains most of what is going on but I'll provide a few more specifics:  I have a model on my controller that contains properties "Name" and "Value"(with possibilities"GOOD" and "BAD")

I have 2 classes defined in my SCSS file to provide styles for "valid" and "invalid" values.

SCSS pseudo.

```
&[class *= "Foo"]
{
  color: green;
}
&[class *= "Bar"]
{
  color: red;
}
```

Markup

```
<ul ng-controller="thingsController">
   <li ng-repeat="thing in things">
      <table >
         <tr >
            <td>{{thing.name}}</td>
            <td ng-class="{'Foo' : true}">{{thing.value}}</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Ok, so the crux of this:
If I use:

```
<td class="Foo">{{thing.value}}</td>
```

it renders value with green text color.
If I use:

```
<td class="Bar">{{thing.value}}</td>
```

it renders value with red text color.

HOWEVER,
If I use:

```
<td ng-class="{'Foo':true}">{{thing.value}}</td>
```

It renders value with black (default) colored text.
(Same for Bar)

When I inspect my element in Chrome Dev Tools, I see

```
<td ng-class="{'Foo':true" class="ng-binding Foo">GOOD</td>
```

but if I inspect the styles tab, the styles within Foo have not been applied to my element...it's nowhere in my cascade.

Can anyone tell what's up with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the cause. It is related to using regex selectors to build a block__element--modifier css structure.

ng-class apparently does not respect the "begins with" css selector.

```
[class ^= "block"]
{
  &[class *= "__element"]
  {
    &[class *= "--modifier"]
    {

    }
  }
}
```

I had to change the initial `[class ^= "block"]` to `[class *= "block"]`
which is absolute crap...but ng-class was able to do what it is supposed to do.

### Edit

The reason that the "Begins With" css selector cannot be used with ng-class is that "begins with" performs a whole string comparison on the value of class.

```
ng-binding
```

gets prepended by Angular to the classes that get applied through the ng-class directive, so the class becomes

```
class="ng-binding foo"
```

...which does not begin with foo.